# R reading values of numeric field in file wrongly

Tags: r, csv, numeric

R is reading the values from a file wrongly. One can check if this statement is true with the following example:

A sample picture/snapshot which explains the problem areas is here[image]

(1) Copy paste the following 10 numbers into a test file (sample.csv)

```
1000522010609612
1000522010609613
1000522010609614
1000522010609615
1000522010609616
1000522010609617
971000522010609612
1501000522010819466
971000522010943717
1501000522010733490
```

(2) Read these contents into R using read.csv

```
X <- read.csv("./test.csv", header=FALSE)
```

(3) Print the output

```
print(head(X, n=10), digits=22)
```

The output I got was

```
                           V1
1     1000522010609612.000000
2     1000522010609613.000000
3     1000522010609614.000000
4     1000522010609615.000000
5     1000522010609616.000000
6     1000522010609617.000000
7   971000522010609664.000000
8  1501000522010819584.000000
9   971000522010943744.000000
10 1501000522010733568.000000
```

The problem is that rows 7,8,9,10 are not correct (check the sample 10 numbers that we considered before).

What could be the problem? Is there some setting that I am missing with my R - terminal?

Comment: It works all right for me...

Comment: I checked the above with R Studio and R console. It is not working for me :-(

Comment: You need to learn about integer limits and floating-point representations in computers, as was gently suggested by akrun in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
library(bit64)
x <- read.csv('sample.csv', header=FALSE, colClasses='integer64')
x
#                   V1
#1     1000522010609612
#2     1000522010609613
#3     1000522010609614
#4     1000522010609615
#5     1000522010609616
#6     1000522010609617
#7   971000522010609612
#8  1501000522010819466
#9   971000522010943717
#10 1501000522010733490
```

If you load the `bit64`, then you can also try `fread` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
x1 <- fread('sample.csv')
x1
#                   V1
#1:    1000522010609612
#2:    1000522010609613
#3:    1000522010609614
#4:    1000522010609615
#5:    1000522010609616
#6:    1000522010609617
#7:  971000522010609612
#8: 1501000522010819466
#9:  971000522010943717
#10: 1501000522010733490
```

Comment: I am retrieving the big integers from a data base into R (using RJDBCs dbGetQuery method). It seems to be automatically converting the data into a dataframe with the corrupted numbers (for bigints). Any suggestion on how we can solve the above problem particularly when we are using dbGetQuery using RJDBC package?

Comment: @acc Sorry, I don't have experience with `RJDBC` package.  Could you ask it as a new post?

Comment: Done that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332693/rjdbc-wrongly-reading-bigintegers-from-database-table

Comment: @acc Thanks, somebody with RJDBC experience will respond.